# Removing or restoring package name

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, namespace

In the first part id the tutorial bellow, created a package name for my account. Then i realized that probably all the components i already had would stop working, so i deleted that prefix, and aparently is now empty. But now all the references to any component has this error:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:cco_SearchBar$controller$searchKeyChange [Cannot read property 'setParams' of null]
Failing descriptor: {c:cco_SearchBar$controller$searchKeyChange}

tutorial http://ccoenraets.github.io/salesforce-lightning-tutorial/create-searchbar-component.html

Trying to fix this, i thought maybe i could restore that namespace, and change those components. but i just cant remember what i put there. So i think the solutions would be one of two:

1. removing and forgoing of this namespace
2. recovering the namespace and correcting it in all components

could someone help me in either of those? Thanks

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Once you add a namespace to your org you cannot remove it. You can see what the org's namespace is by navigating to Setup > Apps > Packaging > Package Manager.

Comment: that was true. But as i thought i could delete this and so i did: the field is empty now. Added a print of it